# qt5: place library with unstandard notation in 'lib' dir on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, ant

I'm using qt5 and qt creator 3.0 to port my app to android. And with the backend of my app, it needs to have library, named foo.iml, in 'lib directory'. When I'm trying to do it, qt creator says: 
"The file name of external library ../lib/foo.iml must begin with "lib" and end with the suffix ".so"."

While googling I discovered that it might be possible to change rules for file names in ant, but I have no ideas how to do it. What's the way to export library with unstandard notation to 'lib' folder? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to have the library suffix unusual .iml?

Comment: @Laszlo Papp Simply because i'm unable to change backend(

Comment: What do you mean, really? Why is it not .lib, .so, .dll, etc rather than .impl? Please elaborate on it. Who provides that for you?